# Usage of \caption command in converting LaTeX files to HTML using tex4ht (For tables)

Tags: captions, conversion, tex4ht

I am looking to convert TeX files into HTML using the htlatex command. I was previously having an issue with the formatting of my HTML file: the captions to my figures were skewed to the left of my page. I was able to correct this by including a configuration file (Thanks to @michal.h21)

Now I am facing a similar kind of problem with the formatting of tables included in my HTML. I've been told I would possibly need more configuration files for the tables.

The MWE to my problem is:

```
\begin{table}
 \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{c}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{figs/tab1.png}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{TestTable}
 \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Any advice would be great! Thanks :)

Comment: I don’t understand: what’s your exact problem, what’s your question? And why do you include a bitmap graphic inside your `tabular`? That looks like misuse very much.

Comment: @Crissov Well my question was this: I have a bunch of figures and Tables which I have acquired in the .png file format. The caption to these tables and figures were skewed to the extreme right of the webpage that I create using the \htlatex command. I need them to be centered below the figure/table.

Also, I've used a image file inside because I have a bitmap which corresponds to a already created table which. It was a work around Ive used because I'm looking to move from a Word based to a LaTex  based system. So in essence I already had a table created which I just want to reuse.

Comment: @Crissov a short term solution till the time I get a grip on creating better tables :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you use `table` and `center` environments in this way, but anyway, try this configuration to catch both current use and more correct use in your first question:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{.figure div.caption, .float div.caption{text-align:center;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Comment: Thanks again @michal.21 :)I'm using both the center and table environments this way because I have seen it being used somewhere when I was learning to use LaTeX. It worked fine and until right now I assumed that's how its to be used. Please correct me if there's a more efficient way :) Thanks again this one also works great :)

Comment: If the HTML source code generated by `htlatex` is any good, `\Css{caption {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}}` should do.

Comment: @Crissov there is lot of css generated by `htlatex` by default, some of it set `text-align` of `div.caption` to left, so we need more complex selectors to override these default settings